# Hibernate: how to specify clustered index annotation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, annotations, clustered-index

I want to create an annotated class similar to that:

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class SeriesMonitoringPointsTable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = ID, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    public void setId( Long id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

In this class I would like to create an Id column as clustered index. Is such thing possible with annotations or hibernate at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it's not possible (although this is the default behavior on the PK with MS SQL Server as reported in issues like [HHH-2377](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2377) or [HHH-3305](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3305)).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is not possible.